# Browser detection problems

Tags: mozilla, browser-detection

I have a website that will be displayed in all browser but I need it to display an alert box on load only in Firefox.

How can I detect the browser and specify that if it is mozilla the alert should pop up?

Answer (score 0):

You could include jQuery in your website and try the following code:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    alert( "this is mozilla!" ); // popup if the browser is mozilla
}
```

PS: Bear in mind that all Mozilla derivates are recognised here.